# SQLAlchemy getting a class object instead of actual result

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I am running a query on an existing Postgres database using automap.

```
Base = automap_base()

Base.prepare(engine, reflect=True)

City = Base.classes.city

dm = session.query(City).first()

Output: <sqlalchemy.ext.automap.city at 0x15f7a87b8>
```

How do I set it up so I can see an actual result from the table?

Comment: Try to print `dir(dm)`

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM it outputs a bunch of methods and a list of column names. I have used a __dict__ to see the actual results and then turned it into a pandas df. Is there a standard way in dealing with this?

Comment: *everything* is a "class object" (if you mean an *instance* of a class). What, exactly, were you *expecting* instead of this output?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I get that, I was hoping to see the actual data in a table or in any other format, list, or dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From comments:

> I have used a dict to see the actual results and then turned it into a pandas df. Is there a standard way in dealing with this?

Just use pandas' `read_sql_query()` method:

```py
Base = automap_base()
Base.prepare(autoload_with=engine)
City = Base.classes.city

query = select(City)
df = pd.read_sql_query(query, engine)
print(df)
"""
   id  city_name prov
0   1    Calgary   AB
1   2  Vancouver   BC
"""
```